# TextView y ProgressBar no muestran los datos Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

He comprobado los datos que debe mostrar son verdaderos mediante un toast que los imprime, pero al querer mostrar en el TextView (lecciones_count) el dato nteoria no lo hace, ni aunque le ponga que muestre un Hola.
pero en donde actualizo progreso_general si lo hace.

el valor de nteoria es 1.

Codigo:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v;
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false);


    progreso(v);
    return v;

}

public void progreso(View v){
    TextView progreso_general = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.General_Count);
    ProgressBar progreso_general_bar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.General_bar);

    int total = totalejercicios+totalteoria;

    progreso_general.setText(String.valueOf(c)+" %");
    progreso_general_bar.setMax(total);
    progreso_general_bar.setProgress(nejercicios+nteoria);

    TextView lecciones_count = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lecciones_count);
    ProgressBar lecciones_bar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.lecciones_bar);

    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(nteoria), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast1.show();

    lecciones_count.setText(String.valueOf(nteoria).concat("/").concat(String.valueOf(totalteoria)));

    lecciones_bar.setMax(totalteoria);
    lecciones_bar.setSecondaryProgress(totalteoria);

    lecciones_bar.setProgress(nteoria);



    TextView ejercicios_count = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ejercicios_count);
    ProgressBar ejercicios_bar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.ejercicios_bar);

    lecciones_count.setText(String.valueOf(nejercicios)+"/"+String.valueOf(totalejercicios));

    lecciones_bar.setMax(totalejercicios);
    lecciones_bar.setSecondaryProgress(totalejercicios);

    lecciones_bar.setProgress(nejercicios);
}
```

XML`

```
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="50sp"
                    android:paddingTop="15sp"
                    android:text="@string/lecciones"
                    android:textSize="26sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lecciones_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0/0"
                    android:textSize="32sp" />

            </LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que veo, es que estas asignando dos veces un valor a `lecciones_count`, pero teniendo en cuenta que no se si las variables están o no vacias, no se si el "problema" pueda venir de lo que comento, pongo tu código con los cambios:

```
public void progreso(View v){
        TextView progreso_general = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.General_Count);
        ProgressBar progreso_general_bar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.General_bar);

        int total = totalejercicios+totalteoria;

        progreso_general.setText(String.valueOf(c)+" %");
        progreso_general_bar.setMax(total);
        progreso_general_bar.setProgress(nejercicios+nteoria);

        TextView lecciones_count = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lecciones_count);
        ProgressBar lecciones_bar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.lecciones_bar);

        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(nteoria), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast1.show();

        lecciones_count.setText(String.valueOf(nteoria).concat("/").concat(String.valueOf(totalteoria)));

        lecciones_bar.setMax(totalteoria);
        lecciones_bar.setSecondaryProgress(totalteoria);

        lecciones_bar.setProgress(nteoria);



        TextView ejercicios_count = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ejercicios_count);
        ProgressBar ejercicios_bar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.ejercicios_bar);

        ejercicios_count.setText(String.valueOf(nejercicios)+"/"+String.valueOf(totalejercicios));

        ejercicios_bar.setMax(totalejercicios);
        ejercicios_bar.setSecondaryProgress(totalejercicios);

        ejercicios_bar.setProgress(nejercicios);
}
```

Los cambios que he realizado, son en las últimas lineas; declaras el `TextView ejercicios_count` y el `ProgressBar ejercicios_bar`, pero justo debajo, asignas el valor a `lecciones_count` y `lecciones_bar`,

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente revisa la secuencia del `TextView` lecciones_count, primeramente obtiene la referencia, asigna un valor mediante `setText()` y posteriormente cambia el valor nuevamente mediante `setText()`:

```
    TextView lecciones_count = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lecciones_count);
    ...
    ...   
lecciones_count.setText(String.valueOf(nteoria).concat("/").concat(String.valueOf(totalteoria)));
    ...
    ...    
lecciones_count.setText(String.valueOf(nejercicios)+"/"+String.valueOf(totalejercicios));
```

> el dato nteoria no lo hace, ni aunque le ponga que muestre un Hola.

**en realidad si realiza el cambio pero posteriormente lo sobreescribe, en esta linea de código:**

```
lecciones_count.setText(String.valueOf(nejercicios)+"/"+String.valueOf(totalejercicios));
```

---

En cuanto al TextView `progreso_general`, defines el texto pero no es modificado posteriormente, por esta razón no ves ningún problema.

```
TextView progreso_general = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.General_Count);
...
...
progreso_general.setText(String.valueOf(c)+" %");
```